# How can i protect my private funcs against reflection executing?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do access modifiers affect reflection also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95974/do-access-modifiers-affect-reflection-also)

I saw this link :

[Do access modifiers affect reflection also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95974/do-access-modifiers-affect-reflection-also)

and ive tried  :

[image]

**How can I prevent reflection to execute my private funcs ?**

Comment: Why this is closed ? The question is totally different then duplicated example