# Don't allow object to be changed

Tags: c#

I have a read-only object but somewhere it's properties getting updated. Does `C#` have anything to restrict that too from direct changes as well as via reflection?

Here is the POC code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadOnlyCreator tester = new ReadOnlyCreator();
        tester.ModifyTester();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class ClassUnderTest
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}

class ReadOnlyCreator
{
    private readonly ClassUnderTest _classUnderTest;
    public ReadOnlyCreator()
    {
        _classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest { SomeProp = "Init" };
    }

    public void ModifyTester()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before: " + _classUnderTest.SomeProp);
        var modifier = new Modifier(_classUnderTest);
        modifier.Modify();
        Console.WriteLine("After: " + _classUnderTest.SomeProp);
    }
}
class Modifier
{
    private ClassUnderTest _classUnderTest;
    public Modifier(ClassUnderTest classUnderTest)
    {
        _classUnderTest = classUnderTest;
    }

    public void Modify()
    {
        _classUnderTest.SomeProp = "Modified";
    }
```

Comment: Readonly in this context means you can't reassign `_classUnderTest`, so `_classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest()` outside of the constructor fails but as you noticed you can still edit the properties of `_classUnderTest`. You'll need to make `set` private or remove it and then use a constructor parameter to set it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I protect my private funcs against reflection executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357469/how-can-i-protect-my-private-funcs-against-reflection-executing)

Comment: _"Does C# have anything to restrict that"_ - yes! It's called [`record`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) and are new in C# 9.  `record`s are **immutable** _reference_ types.  The compiler also synthesizes Public init-only properties for each parameter of a primary constructor.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records#define-compiler-synthesized-methods

Comment: @MickyD records aren't truly immutable; they aren't any more immutable than a type with a `get`-only property, or an `init` property; they change a lot of other things, though; I would absolutely not recommend casually switching to records just to make something quasi-immutable

Comment: @MarcGravell well...darn.  Is that because you can still call the setters from reflection?  Have you got a link?

Comment: @MickyD You can define mutable properties in records. It's right there in your link: _"You can also create record types with mutable properties and fields: ..."_ - just the "default" is "immutable". And of course: reflection destroys everything.

Comment: @Fildor thanks.  Looks like `record` brings along the baggage :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a read only object you should make it read only. i.e.

```
class ClassUnderTest
{
    public string SomeProp { get;  }
    public ClassUnderTest(string someProp) => SomeProp = someProp;
}
```

You could also use [init only setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) if you are using c#9. This allow the property to be set only during construction of the object:

```
class ClassUnderTest
{
    public string SomeProp { get; init; }
}
```

If you are using value types you can (and should) declare the whole type as readonly. See also [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)

```
public readonly struct StructUnderTest
```

This does not protect against reflection or unsafe code. Using these features is deliberately circumventing the rules, so it is up to the developer to ensure it is safe.

Comment: @Liam `struct` by itself doesn't make it immutable; it is the `readonly` in the `readonly struct` that does this, and: that's *what OP wants*; there are *other* implications of the `struct` part though - around equality, boxing, copy-by-value, and a few other things that are far more relevant

Comment: IMO you should add an `init` example, in addition to just linking it

Comment: Since this is new learning for me going forward I am accepting it as answer but in my project C# 8 is used. Is there any thing for c# 8?

Comment: @Imad The first example works just fine in c# 8 and earlier. You will need to create a constructor, but that is usually a good idea anyway to ensure all properties are actually set.